# Ошибка при получении json массива в js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

есть функция, которая отправляет в php данные, и получает json массив, только вот при получении выскакивает

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

js:

```
function configuration_add(to_send, to_data){
        $.post("assets/get.php", { act:"conf", arr:to_send, arrd:to_data})
        .done(function(data) {
            var parse_data = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(parse_data['status']);
            if (parse_data['status'] === 'error'){
                $(".constructor .result_category .get_list[data-id='"+parse_data['idcat']+"']").click();
            }
            if (parse_data['status'] === 'ok'){
                alert("sd");
            }
        });
    }
```

php:

```
if ($action == 'conf'){
    if ($_POST['arr'] && $_POST['arrd']){
        $array = $_POST['arr'];
        $arrayd = $_POST['arrd'];
        $price = 0;
        $arrres = '';
        $tmp = 0;
        $img = '';
        foreach($array as $key => $value) 
          { 
              if ($value == ''){
                  if ($key != 'cooler' && $key != 'os' && $key != 'ssd' && $key != 'cardrider' && $key != 'cviaz' && $key != 'cd' &&  $key != 'block_pit'){
                      $tmp = $tmp + 1;
                      $arrres = array("status"=>"error","idcat"=>$arrayd[$key]);
                      echo json_encode($arrres);
                      exit;
                  }
              }
          }
        if ($tmp > 0) {
            $output.='<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>';
            foreach($array as $key => $value) { 
                $sql = "SELECT mp.`price` as price,mp.`thumb` as thumb,ms.`pagetitle` as pagetitle FROM `modx_site_content` as ms
                LEFT JOIN `modx_ms2_products` mp on mp.`id`=ms.`id`
                where ms.`id`=$value";
                $statement = $modx->query($sql);
                $parent = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                foreach ($parent as $res) {
                    if ($key == 'korpus2') $img = $res['thumb'];
                   $price = $price + $res['price'];
                   $output.='<tr><td>'.$key.'</td><td>'.$res['pagetitle'].'</td></tr>';
                }
            }

            $output.='</tbody></table>';
            $arrres = array("status"=>"ok","ord"=>$output,"price"=>$price,'imag'=>$img);
            echo json_encode($arrres);
        }
        //echo $array['korpus2'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте сюда пожалуйста `JSON` Данные, чтобы мы могли понять в чем дело.

Comment: я это исправил, теперь вместо этой ошибки выскакивает http://technogik.ru/assets/get.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: $arrres = array("status"=>"ok","ord"=>$output,"price"=>$price,'imag'=>$img);

Comment: `.done(function(data) { console.log(typeof data, data); ...` -?

Comment: @Aslero нет, мне надо чтобы вы скинули `JSON` Который получили из `json_decode`.

Comment: @Aslero это ошибка сервера, видимо исправляясь что-то зацепили.

Comment: разобрался, здесь поставил одинарные кавычки и заработало ms.`id`=$value";